# data not being inputted properly using cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have two data structures (both with a Category item). I'm using numberOfRowsInSection to determine the number of rows with a specific category (based on an index passed using prepareForSegue from the previous screen).

The numberOfRowsInSection function is working (i.e. the screen shows the correct number of rows).

Now I'd like to actually display the correct content on each row.

My logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't seem to be correct because in some cases cell.vendorName.text displays the correct data, and in other cases it displays "No Value".

How would I tweak the following code in order to ONLY display data related to a particular category type which was selected on the previous screen.

```
class VendorFetchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let categoryData = Data().headerData
let vendorData = Data().vendorData

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

var index: Int?


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // warning incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let categoryData = Data().headerData
    let vendorData = Data().vendorData

    let category = categoryData[index!]
    let categoryType = category.category

    var count: Int = 0

    for (var i=0; i < vendorData.count; i++) {

        if vendorData[i].category == categoryType {

            count = count + 1
        }
    }

    return count
 }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("vendorCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VendorSelectionTableViewCell

    let category = categoryData[index!]
    let categoryType = category.category


        if vendorData[indexPath.row].category == categoryType {
            //the UILabel for VendorName is in a UITableViewCell file which is connected to the Prototype Cell in the TableViewController
            cell.vendorName.text = vendorData[indexPath.row].name
            print(vendorData[indexPath.row].category)
            print(categoryType)
        } else {
            cell.vendorName.text = "No Value"
        }

    return cell
}

}
```

The following is Data.swift file:

```
class Data {

class Entry {

    let filename: String
    let heading: String
    let headerSub: String
    let description: String
    let category: String

    init(profilePicture: String, profileTitle: String, profileSub: String, description: String, category: String) {
        self.heading = profileTitle
        self.filename = profilePicture
        self.headerSub = profileSub
        self.description = description
        self.category = category
    }

}

let headerData = [

    Entry(profilePicture: "sampleImage.png", profileTitle: "Title1", profileSub: "Sub1", description: "Desc1", category: "Category1"),
Entry(profilePicture: "sampleImage2.png", profileTitle: "Title2", profileSub: "Sub2", description: "Desc2", category: "Category2"),
Entry(profilePicture: "sampleImage3.png", profileTitle: "Title3", profileSub: "Sub3", description: "Desc3", category: "Category3"),
]


class Vendor {

    let pictureFilename: String
    let name: String
    let review: Double
    let reviewNumber: Int
    let address: String
    let cost: Int
    let category: String

    init(profilePicture: String, name: String, review: Double, reviewNumber: Int, address: String, cost: Int, category: String) {
        self.pictureFilename = profilePicture
        self.name = name
        self.review = review
        self.reviewNumber = reviewNumber
        self.address = address
        self.cost = cost
        self.category = category
    }
}

let vendorData = [

    Vendor(profilePicture: "vendor1.png", name: "name1", review: 4.7, reviewNumber: 100, address: "Add1", cost: 30, category: "Category1"),
     Vendor(profilePicture: "vendor2.png", name: "name2", review: 5.0, reviewNumber: 23, address: "Add2", cost: 35, category: "Category2"),
    Vendor(profilePicture: "vendor3.png", name: "name3", review: 4.7, reviewNumber: 100, address: "Add3", cost: 30, category: "Category3")


]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample code? So we can help you better.

Comment: Hey @Karlos, Thanks....I just added all of the related code.

Comment: In tableview func didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can get the indexPath of the selected category. Using the indexPath you can get the category name.

Comment: Thanks @Karlos, I'll try didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but in my code above, I tried using indexPath.row with cellForRowAtIndexPath ... what's the difference between the two functions?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is used to add the data in you tableview and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called when you select a particular cell in you table view. You did not set the tableview delegate. Check the following link for tableview tutorial. It will help you.
http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/
https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: Very helpful @Karlos ... thank you!